# Python start browser with current user directory on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-webbrowser

I want to open web browser with url my python script.

I have a more than 100+ user. I want to run the my python script with every user desktop portable chrome for ex. C:\Users\user1\Desktop\chrome\chrome.exe

My code;
`import webbrowser import os url = 'http://example.com/' webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(r"C:\Users\**user1**\Desktop\chrome\chrome.exe")) webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)`

I want the name of the user running the python file in the user part . Each user's desktop has the same exe file in the same folder. Single variable user part ex. C:\Users\user1, C:\Users\user2\ ...

Thanks for helping.

When **user10** starts the python file, open the browser with portable chrome in the chrome folder on **user10's desktop**.

Comment: Try this: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\chrome\chrome.exe`

Comment: @Meh not working.

Comment: Then you can use `os.getlogin()` function to get the current user. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Meh yes this may work for me what do i need to change on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution, all it does, is simply using `os.getlogin()` function which returns the username of the current user and assign it to username variable, then the username variable is being used as part of the path.

````py
import webbrowser
import os

username = os.getlogin()
url = 'http://example.com/'
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\chrome\\chrome.exe'))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)```
````

Comment: Hi @Meh thanks for helping, I getting a error "unexcepted character after line continuation character" for  **D**esktop\chrome\chrome.exe

Comment: @EnesAksu Oops! My bad, fixed it.